# Manage Array of object to custom tree(reverse) data

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tree

I am having Array of object like below

key value with children pairs as a tree. for exact result please refer the screen shot attached

I have tried it with many things but not bale to achive above image type of result.

Comment: your data contains an array, but no key for it.

Comment: Data is invalid.

Comment: Updated The Data now

Comment: @gauravthakkar, please edit the question and add the data (a small amount would be ok), the wante keys for grouping and a small result along with your former try. this would make more sense for my answer than without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by the given keys and return an array with the wanted grouping for every level.

```js
const
    data = [{ HLT: "Infections NEC", LLT: "Adrenalitis", HLGT: "Infections - pathogen unspecified", PT: "Adrenalitis", SOC: "Infections and infestations" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms", LLT: "Adrenal cyst", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal cyst", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal mass", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal mass", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenomegaly", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenomegaly", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal nodule", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal mass", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland therapeutic procedures", LLT: "Adrenalectomy", HLGT: "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures", PT: "Adrenalectomy", SOC: "Surgical and medical procedures" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal crisis", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenocortical insufficiency acute", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal atrophy", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal atrophy", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified NEC", LLT: "Adrenal neoplasm", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenal neoplasm", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal disorders congenital", LLT: "Adrenal virilism", HLGT: "Endocrine disorders congenital", PT: "Adrenogenital syndrome", SOC: "Congenital, familial and genetic disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms benign", LLT: "Adrenal adenoma", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms benign", PT: "Adrenal adenoma", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal hematoma", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal haematoma", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal bleeding", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal haemorrhage", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal disorder", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal disorder", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Cerebral disorders congenital", LLT: "Adrenoleukodystrophy", HLGT: "Neurological disorders congenital", PT: "Adrenoleukodystrophy", SOC: "Congenital, familial and genetic disorders" }, { HLT: "Abdominal and gastrointestinal injuries NEC", LLT: "Adrenal gland injury", HLGT: "Injuries NEC", PT: "Adrenal gland injury", SOC: "Injury, poisoning and procedural complications" }, { HLT: "Metastases to specified sites", LLT: "Adrenal metastases", HLGT: "Metastases", PT: "Metastases to adrenals", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms malignant", LLT: "Adrenal gland cancer", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenal gland cancer", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms benign", LLT: "Adrenal myelolipoma", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms benign", PT: "Benign neoplasm of adrenal gland", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Autonomic nervous system disorders", LLT: "Adrenolytic syndrome", HLGT: "Neuromuscular disorders", PT: "Adrenolytic syndrome", SOC: "Nervous system disorders" }, { HLT: "Endocrine analyses and imaging NEC", LLT: "Adrenal scintigraphy", HLGT: "Endocrine investigations (incl sex hormones)", PT: "Scan adrenal gland", SOC: "Investigations" }, { HLT: "Pituitary analyses anterior", LLT: "Adrenocorticotropin", HLGT: "Endocrine investigations (incl sex hormones)", PT: "Blood corticotrophin", SOC: "Investigations" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal thrombosis", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal thrombosis", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal hypofunction", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal insufficiency", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland therapeutic procedures", LLT: "Adrenalectomy NOS", HLGT: "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures", PT: "Adrenalectomy", SOC: "Surgical and medical procedures" }, { HLT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified NEC", LLT: "Adrenal neoplasm NOS", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenal neoplasm", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms malignant", LLT: "Adrenal carcinoma", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenal gland cancer", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Autonomic nervous system disorders", LLT: "Adrenergic syndrome", HLGT: "Neuromuscular disorders", PT: "Adrenergic syndrome", SOC: "Nervous system disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland histopathology procedures", LLT: "Adrenal gland biopsy", HLGT: "Endocrine investigations (incl sex hormones)", PT: "Biopsy adrenal gland", SOC: "Investigations" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal haematoma", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal haematoma", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal haemorrhage", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal haemorrhage", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal hemorrhage", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal haemorrhage", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal disorder NOS", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal disorder", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal suppression", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal suppression", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal disorders congenital", LLT: "Adrenogenital syndrome", HLGT: "Endocrine disorders congenital", PT: "Adrenogenital syndrome", SOC: "Congenital, familial and genetic disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal cortex necrosis", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal cortex necrosis", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal cortex atrophy", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal atrophy", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Hormonal therapeutic procedures NEC", LLT: "Adrenal blockade therapy", HLGT: "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures", PT: "Adrenal blockade therapy", SOC: "Surgical and medical procedures" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland therapeutic procedures", LLT: "Adrenal gland operation", HLGT: "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures", PT: "Adrenal gland operation", SOC: "Surgical and medical procedures" }, { HLT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified NEC", LLT: "Adrenal incidentaloma", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenal neoplasm", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms malignant", LLT: "Adrenal adenocarcinoma", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenal gland cancer", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Adrenal neoplasms malignant", LLT: "Adrenocortical carcinoma", HLGT: "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified", PT: "Adrenocortical carcinoma", SOC: "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)" }, { HLT: "Infections NEC", LLT: "Adrenal gland abscess", HLGT: "Infections - pathogen unspecified", PT: "Adrenal gland abscess", SOC: "Infections and infestations" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal gland enlarged", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenomegaly", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal cortical necrosis", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal cortex necrosis", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal gland disorders NEC", LLT: "Adrenal cortex dysplasia", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal cortex dysplasia", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal insufficiency", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal insufficiency", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions", LLT: "Adrenal insufficiency NOS", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal insufficiency", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hyperfunctions", LLT: "Adrenal androgen excess", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Adrenal androgen excess", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }, { HLT: "Adrenal cortical hyperfunctions", LLT: "Adrenal hypercorticism", HLGT: "Adrenal gland disorders", PT: "Hyperadrenocorticism", SOC: "Endocrine disorders" }],
    keys = ['SOC', 'HLGT', 'HLT', 'PT', 'LLT'],
    groupBy = (data, keys) => {
        if (!keys.length) return [];

        const
            key = keys[0],
            getValue = key => object => object[key];

        return Object
            .entries(Object.groupBy(data, getValue(key)))
            .map(([value, data]) => ({ key, value, children: groupBy(data, keys.slice(1)) }));
    },
    result = groupBy(data, keys);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your ans, but i want the data like 
[{key:'SOC',value:'Infections and infestations',children:[ {key:'HLGT',value:'value one',children:[] }]}] key value with children pairs as a tree.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please help me for the same?

Comment: @gauravthakkar, please see edit.

Comment: Yes it will work for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check it.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "HLT": "Infections NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenalitis",
    "HLGT": "Infections - pathogen unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenalitis",
    "SOC": "Infections and infestations"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms",
    "LLT": "Adrenal cyst",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal cyst",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal mass",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal mass",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenomegaly",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenomegaly",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal nodule",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal mass",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland therapeutic procedures",
    "LLT": "Adrenalectomy",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures",
    "PT": "Adrenalectomy",
    "SOC": "Surgical and medical procedures"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal crisis",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenocortical insufficiency acute",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal atrophy",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal atrophy",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal neoplasm",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal neoplasm",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal disorders congenital",
    "LLT": "Adrenal virilism",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine disorders congenital",
    "PT": "Adrenogenital syndrome",
    "SOC": "Congenital, familial and genetic disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms benign",
    "LLT": "Adrenal adenoma",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms benign",
    "PT": "Adrenal adenoma",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal hematoma",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal haematoma",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal bleeding",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal haemorrhage",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal disorder",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal disorder",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Cerebral disorders congenital",
    "LLT": "Adrenoleukodystrophy",
    "HLGT": "Neurological disorders congenital",
    "PT": "Adrenoleukodystrophy",
    "SOC": "Congenital, familial and genetic disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Abdominal and gastrointestinal injuries NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal gland injury",
    "HLGT": "Injuries NEC",
    "PT": "Adrenal gland injury",
    "SOC": "Injury, poisoning and procedural complications"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Metastases to specified sites",
    "LLT": "Adrenal metastases",
    "HLGT": "Metastases",
    "PT": "Metastases to adrenals",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms malignant",
    "LLT": "Adrenal gland cancer",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal gland cancer",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms benign",
    "LLT": "Adrenal myelolipoma",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms benign",
    "PT": "Benign neoplasm of adrenal gland",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Autonomic nervous system disorders",
    "LLT": "Adrenolytic syndrome",
    "HLGT": "Neuromuscular disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenolytic syndrome",
    "SOC": "Nervous system disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Endocrine analyses and imaging NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal scintigraphy",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine investigations (incl sex hormones)",
    "PT": "Scan adrenal gland",
    "SOC": "Investigations"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Pituitary analyses anterior",
    "LLT": "Adrenocorticotropin",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine investigations (incl sex hormones)",
    "PT": "Blood corticotrophin",
    "SOC": "Investigations"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal thrombosis",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal thrombosis",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal hypofunction",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal insufficiency",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland therapeutic procedures",
    "LLT": "Adrenalectomy NOS",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures",
    "PT": "Adrenalectomy",
    "SOC": "Surgical and medical procedures"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal neoplasm NOS",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal neoplasm",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms malignant",
    "LLT": "Adrenal carcinoma",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal gland cancer",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Autonomic nervous system disorders",
    "LLT": "Adrenergic syndrome",
    "HLGT": "Neuromuscular disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenergic syndrome",
    "SOC": "Nervous system disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland histopathology procedures",
    "LLT": "Adrenal gland biopsy",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine investigations (incl sex hormones)",
    "PT": "Biopsy adrenal gland",
    "SOC": "Investigations"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal haematoma",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal haematoma",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal haemorrhage",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal haemorrhage",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal hemorrhage",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal haemorrhage",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal disorder NOS",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal disorder",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal suppression",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal suppression",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal disorders congenital",
    "LLT": "Adrenogenital syndrome",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine disorders congenital",
    "PT": "Adrenogenital syndrome",
    "SOC": "Congenital, familial and genetic disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal cortex necrosis",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal cortex necrosis",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal cortex atrophy",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal atrophy",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Hormonal therapeutic procedures NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal blockade therapy",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures",
    "PT": "Adrenal blockade therapy",
    "SOC": "Surgical and medical procedures"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland therapeutic procedures",
    "LLT": "Adrenal gland operation",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine gland therapeutic procedures",
    "PT": "Adrenal gland operation",
    "SOC": "Surgical and medical procedures"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal incidentaloma",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal neoplasm",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms malignant",
    "LLT": "Adrenal adenocarcinoma",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal gland cancer",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal neoplasms malignant",
    "LLT": "Adrenocortical carcinoma",
    "HLGT": "Endocrine neoplasms malignant and unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenocortical carcinoma",
    "SOC": "Neoplasms benign, malignant and unspecified (incl cysts and polyps)"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Infections NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal gland abscess",
    "HLGT": "Infections - pathogen unspecified",
    "PT": "Adrenal gland abscess",
    "SOC": "Infections and infestations"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal gland enlarged",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenomegaly",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal cortical necrosis",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal cortex necrosis",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal gland disorders NEC",
    "LLT": "Adrenal cortex dysplasia",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal cortex dysplasia",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal insufficiency",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal insufficiency",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hypofunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal insufficiency NOS",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal insufficiency",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hyperfunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal androgen excess",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Adrenal androgen excess",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  },
  {
    "HLT": "Adrenal cortical hyperfunctions",
    "LLT": "Adrenal hypercorticism",
    "HLGT": "Adrenal gland disorders",
    "PT": "Hyperadrenocorticism",
    "SOC": "Endocrine disorders"
  }
]


    const treeData = {
      name: "My Tree",
      children: []
    };

    data.forEach((item) => {
      let currentNode = treeData;
      ["SOC", "HLGT", "HLT", "PT", "LLT"].forEach((key) => {
        let childNode = currentNode.children.find((child) => child.name === item[key]);
        if (!childNode) {
          childNode = { name: item[key], children: [] };
          currentNode.children.push(childNode);
        }
        currentNode = childNode;
      });
    });

    const width = 1960;
    const height = 1600;

    const svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

    const tree = d3.tree().size([height, width - 160]);

    const root = d3.hierarchy(treeData);
    tree(root);

    const link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(root.links())
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
        .x((d) => d.y)
        .y((d) => d.x));

    const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`);

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

    node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("x", (d) => d.children ? -13 : 13)
      .style("text-anchor", (d) => d.children ? "end" : "start")
      .text((d) => d.data.name);
```

```css
.node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```